# Overflow: hidden problems

Tags: html, css, facebook-like, overflow

I have a facebook like button in the caption part of a slideshow div, which is in the far bottom right. Obviously, the slideshow container has `overflow: hidden`, and when you click like the 'post to wall' bit pops up, below the like button. As expected, this is cut off.. but I need it to be visible. I have tried z-index and position: absolute with no luck.. any suggestions please?

You can see the site here: `http://65.39.128.45/~apretty/category/habitat/`

Comment: Please read over this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: @OkamiStudio I am aware of this.. I didn't just 'describe the problem and paste a link' - I knew what / where the problem was and I gave two examples of things I have already tried

Comment: It would help if you posted the relevant code and a jsFiddle

Comment: @apaul34208 The code is irrelevant - I specified all of the important parts above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the like button outside the element with `overflow: hidden` since no children to an element with `overflow: hidden` can overflow the parent...

Comment: Are you 100% sure? I thought was the case but I thought there might have been a work around (I thought remove the element from the flow of the DOM would do it but nope.. :( )

Comment: Quite sure, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901264/different-overflow-behavior-for-divs-in-same-container but this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387489/make-child-visible-outside-an-overflowhidden-parent